# Computing sum for an array outside *newb*

Tags: c#, arrays

I've figured out how to do most of what I need. I realize that the variables used in the for loops will not be reachable outside of the loop, but I need to display the sum of the integers the user puts in. So,

**step 1:** Asks user for input of number of integers.

**Step 2:** Runs through getting each integer.

**Step 3:** Then displays all input.

**And step 4:** should have the sum of step 3...and that's

where my issue is.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Dynamic_Entry
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("How many integers are in your list? ");
            int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] a = new int[k];
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter an integer: ");
                a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            for (int n = 0; n < a.Length; n++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0, 5}", a[n]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-----");

            sum += [] a;
            Console.Write("{0, 5}", sum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help on how to get the sum from outside the loop? If I put the hyphen line inside the last loop, it'll keep putting lines after every number...I only need the line at the end, with the sum under it. Thanks!

Comment: put the addition to sum into the for loop

Comment: You can declare `int sum = 0;` up top, then `sum += a[i];` as you read them in.

Comment: I can't add the addition into the loop, because then it makes the output wrong. The final sum is displayed after the hyphen line, which is outside of the loop. If the hyphen line was inside the loop, I'd get a line after every integer entered.

Comment: Why does that make the output wrong?

Comment: Because it had to be a certain format. Having a line under every integer entered was not the format the output was supposed to have. The program displays all integers in a neat row, then has the hyphen line, then displays the sum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can used linq, replace the sum with bellow

```
 Console.WriteLine("-----");
    sum = a.Sum(); 
 Console.Write("{0, 5}", sum);
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I needed. Can you explain how the array a still keeps the value of the array while it is in the different loops?

Comment: Same answer I gave before this answer.

Comment: U are just iterating the array not changing the value of the array. That's why Same values are being kept. Very common sense

Comment: Hi Atish Dipongkor, sorry to duplicate your answer, because when i submit the answer the time, your answer not yet show out, cause just 4 min different.

Comment: Atish, your original answer was to use Array.Sum, which did not exist. a.Sum did, and that is what Harris posted first.

Comment: @user1707042 Array.Sum() means yourArray.Sum(). I thought that You will be able to get it.

Comment: @AtishDipongkor votes are not just given for technical content but also for the clarity it can be conveyed to the reader. If the OP found your explanation less clear than this one he is in full right to rather select this one, even if it was due to something that you thought was obvious and this answer thought was not. Show a little sportsmanship.

Comment: @Cornelius I am totally agreed with you. But my answer was not very much inconvenient for OP. If my answer is inconvenient, then OP should ask me something by adding comment. Because I paid attention to him first. Shouldn't he give me the chance to make everything clear?

Comment: Atish, mind you that I put *newb* in the title for a reason. I'm still learning, and if you answer with code that doesn't work for my specific case, I'm not going to choose your answer as the best. Harris put the exact code in that worked for me. I tried yours first, and it didn't work. Array.Sum() vs a.Sum() may seem trivial to you, but considering I'm still a newb, it's a big difference to me, and meant the difference between the code working, or not.

Comment: @user1707042 yes it is. If something is inconvenient to you, then feel welcome to add comment for the next time. And consider the person who pay attention first. Thanks.

Comment: @HarrisYer because I want to answer one question very much clearly. I was waiting for OP's reply.

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
a.Sum()
```

method of Linq.

And your code should look like following

```
static void Main()
        {
            Console.Write("How many integers are in your list? ");
            int k = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            int[] a = new int[k];
            int sum = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write("Please enter an integer: ");
                a[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            }
            for (int n = 0; n < a.Length; n++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0, 5}", a[n]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("-----");

            Console.Write("{0, 5}", a.Sum());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: I don't have a Apply.Sum option in my Visual Studio. This is a console application, btw.

Comment: I didn't tell u to use Apply.Sum(). I told u to use Array.Sum(). Your accepted answer was given after my answer. What's the problem with my answer. Seems something wrong here

Comment: I didn't have Array.Sum, simple misspelling. In other words, when I tried your code, it didn't work. When I tried Harris', it did. No hard feelings.

Comment: Man ..... Array.Sum() is a method of LINQ. That means you can use Sum() method with your Array